# Item reassignment with pandas gives wrong results

Tags: python, pandas

I'm modifying the values for column 'x' resulting in different dataframes as seen here. I find that reassignment results in absurd values when instead all the four dataframes should be the same.

Here's how the code looks,

```
import pandas as pd

def modifyspec(df,i,val=0.25):  
    df['x'][(df['z']>=9) & (df['z']<=19)] = (df['x'][(df['z']>=9) & (df['z']<=19)] - (val))/(val)
    df.to_csv('{}file.csv'.format(i),sep='\t',index=False)
    return


x=[1.1,1.2345,3.3456,4.4442,5.555,6.21234,7.3434]
y=[2.23,2.456,6.8899,9.222,10.999,13.1111,15.44545]
z=[5.44,6.99,8.99,11.33,13.33,19.002,28.445]
dfx=pd.DataFrame({'x': x,'y': y,'z':z})


for i in range(4):
    modifyspec(dfx,i,0.25)
```

I don't understand this behavior, could someone point out how to produce same result in all the four files (produced using the for loop).

Comment: Can you change it to use `df.loc['x', ...]` instead of `df['x'][...]`, it's more standard so will be easier to follow. I would also suggest assigning `(df['z']>=9) & (df['z']<=19)` to a variable like `idx` again for readability.

Comment: Are you trying to modify `dfx` at each loop iteration? If not, you might want to include `df = df.copy()` at the start of your function. Python is passing a reference to `dfx` to the function, so when you change `df` inside your function, you are actually changing `dfx` outside as it is a reference to the same object. If you don't want this, you need to make a copy inside the function. Also, why do you have just `return`? If you're returning nothing, you don't need to write return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is due to your function mutating `df` which is a reference to a DataFrame outside the scope of your function. To fix this, make a copy inside to the function and mutate the copy instead:

```
def modifyspec(df, prefix, val=0.25):
    df = df.copy()
    row_idx = (df['z'] >= 9) & (df['z'] <= 19)
    df.loc['x', row_idx] = (df.loc['x', row_idx] - val) / val
    df.to_csv(f'{prefix}file.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```